# how to create moving div up and down on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can i **create moving div** like on this *site* (on right side of slider)
 [Click to see div on web](http://www.sodamco-weber.com/home.html)
 with javascript or jquery ?

Comment: you can use carousel jQuery-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertical carousel on this page (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php) might help you out.

You can Google for jQuery carousel and you will find a lot of further tutorials and downloads for this.

```
<div class="slideshow vertical" 
    data-cycle-fx=carousel
    data-cycle-timeout=0
    data-cycle-next="#next3"
    data-cycle-prev="#prev3"
    data-cycle-pager="#pager3"
    data-cycle-carousel-visible=2
    data-cycle-carousel-vertical=true
    >
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg">
    ...
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach9.jpg">
</div>

<div class=center>
    <a href=# id=prev3><< Prev </a>
    <a href=# id=next3> Next >> </a>
</div>

<div class="cycle-pager" id=pager3></div>
```